# Flutter release for iOS: Product > Archive fails with 'file not found'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm following the [Preparing an iOS App For Release](https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/ios) guide on flutter.io.

The `flutter build ios` command succeeds. But when I open Xcode and do `Product > Archive` I get this error:

```
cloud_firestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you open `Runner.xcworkspace` and not `Runner.xcodeproj` as the latter does not have access to Pods.

Comment: I love you so much, I legit can't read. I spent 2 full days on this and this was the issue. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! Saved my live.

Comment: I signed up specifically to SO just to thank you for your answer. This did the job for me.

Comment: You helped me! Thanx